# Grant permission of specific folder in android studio SDK 30

Tags: android, android-studio, whatsapp, android-11

I wanted to grant permission of the folder android/media. Also I don't want to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission as google play store will reject my application according to their policies for android 11 storage. I found an application on google play that is granting permission for the folder android/media. I am a beginner in this field, I just wanted to know how can I grant this permission like this application. [Granting Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr4XY.jpg) [From File Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1JMt.jpg)

Comment: `folder android/media. ` ??? Dont know that folder. Please post full path.

Comment: `I wanted to grant permission` You cannot grant anything. You can request a permission. Or obtain one. But you cannot grant it to yourself or another app.

Comment: I meant "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses". Also see the screenshots attached.

Comment: That is not an existing path. Not possible. Please post full path.

Comment: That path is just for an example tell me how can I request a permission as shown in the screenshots.

Comment: If you dont even know the right path.. And there are no paths visible in the screenshots..

Comment: Let's say the example is called /Android